# how to store multiple string into single string and how to make key for the particular string

Tags: java, android

I am storing my string data as following way.Now I want to make key for every string and storing these string into a single string.The key for every string should be unique.

```
  public static final String[] titles = new String[] { "Google",
            "Apple", "Android", "IOS","Google" };

    public static final String[] descriptions = new String[] {
            "Google is a search engine Google is.",
            "Google is a search engine .",
            "Google is a search engine.",
            "Google is a search engine."=
           };

    public static final String[] url = new String[] {
            "www.google.com",
            "www.apple.com", "www.android.com",
            "www.ios.com" 
            };


    Integer[] imageId = {
            R.drawable.place,
            R.drawable.place,
            R.drawable.place,
            R.drawable.place

    };
    ListView listView;
    List<RowItem> rowItems;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Typeface font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/cabin.regular.ttf");
        txtArticle=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.main_title);
        txtArticle.setTypeface(font1); txtArticle.setTextSize(18.0f);

        rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
            RowItem item = new RowItem(imageId[i], titles[i], descriptions[i], url[i]);
            rowItems.add(item);
        }
```

Comment: what you want to do actually?

Comment: You could append each String together (you should use StringBuilder for this) and insert a certain split-sign inbetween (e.g. `;` but also `now begins a new String in 3 2 1 go:` would be possible.). Or you could just use a `Map` (why are so many people not using the API?)

Comment: I want to store multiple string's array data into single string.The data of substring array must have a key unique.In my code I want to store titile[],des[],url[] strings array data into single array.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest create a Class to store your string data, you can call it for example StringData

```
public class StringData {

   private String title;
   private String description;
   private String url;


   public StringData(String title, String description, String url) {
       this.title = title;
       this.description = description;
       this.url = url;
   }


   public String getTitle() {
       return title;
   }


   public String getDescription() {
       return description;
   }


   public String getUrl() {
       return url;
   }
```

}

And then use it

```
    Map<String, StringData> myMap = new HashMap<>();

    // Create the objects
    StringData ggl = new StringData("Google", "description of google", "http://www.google.com");
    StringData apl = new StringData("Apple", "description of apple", "http://www.apple.com");
    StringData and = new StringData("Android", "description of android", "http://www.android.com");

    // Store them in a map
    myMap.put("google", ggl);
    myMap.put("apple", apl);
    myMap.put("android", and);

    // Get the info as you want

    String titleApple = myMap.get("apple").getTitle();
    String descriptionApple = myMap.get("apple").getDescription();
    String urlApple =  myMap.get("apple").getUrl();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use the Hashmap (key,value) : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_hashmap_class.htm